# Recyclerview memoryusage output, is this normal with large images?

Tags: android, memory, android-recyclerview

My recyclerview's scroll memory usage looks like this :

[image]

Is this kind of memory usage and garbage collection expected ? I dont see any out-of-memory or lag while scrolling .

Comment: We probably need a bit more data to characterize what is going on.  Are you using images in the item views?

Comment: Yes The list contains high resolution images of size around 200bytes and the number of rows is 10-15

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the allocation tracker within the Android Device Monitor to see what's going on, but if you're using images I wouldn't be surprised to see this sort of churn.